# Interact with metamask with reactjs and web3js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I was starting to create a simple dapp using reactjs and web3js but I don't know how I can connect with metamask to listen for changees to the account and the chainId without reloading the page. I also want to switch between network without reloading.

Comment: You would have done a greater job if you shared how you're currently listening for account and chain changes.

Answer (score 0):

Switching networks in MetaMask can be done with the following code:

```
// Ethereum
await window.ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
  params: [{ chainId: ethers.utils.hexValue('1') }]
});

// Polygon Mumbai
await window.ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
  params: [{ chainId: ethers.utils.hexValue('80001') }]
});
```

Set these listeners inside your connect function

```
ethereum.on('accountsChanged', async () => {
  ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"})
    .then(async (accounts: string[]) => {
      // fired when account is changed
    })
    .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
});


ethereum.on('chainChanged', (chainId) => {
  // fired when chain is changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried this also on console?

// polygon mainnet
await window.ethereum.request({method:'eth_chainId',params:[]})

to see in which ID are you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).